# Page Condition becomes false after the ajax call in wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to avoid some code to get display on particular pages such as tags categories and other pages.

```
if( !is_front_page() && !is_search() && !is_page( 'article', 'preview' ) && !is_category() && !is_tax() && !is_tag() ){
//code goes here..
}
```

The condition works fine when a user lands on the page. But these pages uses ajax to retrieve post and when this happens the condition becomes false and unnecessary code displayed on page.

Why is this happening? Do anyone has any idea about this. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an additional constraint to the if statement to check if the request is an ajax request. This is not used on every server, but if you are using Apache it should work for you.

```
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && !is_front_page() && !is_search() && !is_page( 'article', 'preview' ) && !is_category() && !is_tax() && !is_tag() ){
 //code here 
}
```

The above will only be true if it is NOT an ajax request. In the event that an ajax request is made to this php file `strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'` should be true and this is how you can check if it is an ajax request and handle it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You should get your Ajax response data with above condition .

Or you can pass one variable(argument) in your Ajax when you are in that page which you don't want to show that code, that time that will pass in your Ajax and when Ajax function get that variable(argument) that time you have to add your above condition if you not get(empty) argument then you perform for all page.

better way is get your response for Ajax in a way by which you can get above page condition.